# c++ - 2d collision detection issue

Tags: c++, collision-detection

I'm working on just a basic square-square collision detection system that checks a player and a bunch of tiles. The problem is that since it works going through the tiles starting from the top left most tile (in the stage) to the bottom right most tile it checks collisions with tiles above and to the left of the player before anything else. Because of this, if you're moving left and up against a wall, you get stuck because it corrects the players Y position for the tile above before the X position for the tile to the left (or right). Just wondering how i can go about fixing this. Collision code is as follows:

```
for(std::vector<Tile*>::iterator tile = tiles.begin(); tile != tiles.end(); tile++) {
    if((*tile)->tileType == Tile::TILE_WALL) {
        float cx = character->getPosition().x;
        float cy = character->getPosition().y;
        float chw = character->halfWidth();
        float chh = character->halfHeight();
        float thw = Tile::TILE_WIDTH/2;
        float thh = Tile::TILE_HEIGHT/2;
        float dx = cx - ((*tile)->getPosition().x);
        float dy = cy - ((*tile)->getPosition().y);
        if(fabsf(dy) < chh + thh) {
            if(fabsf(dx) < chw + thw) {
                float ox = chw + thw - fabsf(dx);
                float oy = chh + thh - fabsf(dy);
                if(ox > oy) {
                    if(dy > 0) {
                        character->setPosition(cx, cy + oy);
                    }
                    else {
                        character->setPosition(cx, cy - oy);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(dx > 0) {
                        character->setPosition(cx + ox, cy);
                    }
                    else {
                        character->setPosition(cx - ox, cy);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, any optimization to this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have the if(ox >oy){ adjust the y position} else {adjust the x position}.  It seems like you would want to adjust overlaps in both if they existed.

Comment: if you hit a corner between two tiles, it kind of explodes without it for some reason.

Comment: How many tiles do you plan to have? There's some possible optimizations by using more exotic tree structures but it's not worth the effort unless you have a lot of tiles to consider.

Comment: There will be a decent amount, split into floors in some cases. I've looked into quad trees, but not much as of yet.